# Prove that this function is bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set and $A \subset S$

$$f(A) = S \setminus A$$

How would you prove that this is injective/surjective? It seems really intuitive for both because for example for surjectivity, $S \setminus A$ will always be in the power set of $S$, which means all subsets (results of $f(A)$) can be denoted that way. 
What is the mathematical proof for these two? Thanks!

Comment: There is a definition for "bijection", and you need to begin by understanding it, then by showing that $f$ satisfies this definition.

Comment: What are domains and codomains of $f$?

Comment: Dude, solve your CS22 homework by yourself!

Comment: @BrownsAcademicCode LOL

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

What is $(f\circ f)(A)$?

Comment: How do you prove that S \ (S \ A) is A though? Like I can provide an example, but not mathematically.

Comment: That is because $A$ and $S\setminus A$ is a partition of $S$ (if $A$ is not empty, nor equal to $S$).

Answer (score 0):

Just check the definitions:

- For injectivity, show that if $A,B\subseteq S$ and $A\ne B$, then $f(A)\ne f(B)$, i.e., that $S\setminus A\ne S\setminus B$.
- For surjectivity, show that for any $A\subseteq S$, $A=f(S\setminus A)$.